# C# Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting mschart add different back image in each DataPoint

Tags: c#, charts, data-visualization

Box plot chart's data source have scatter points. 
 
I would like to add these scatter point image on each DataPoint of Box Plot Chart. 
Is it possible to add different back image in each DataPoint? 
or is it possible to get rectangle of each DataPoint to allow me override Paint method?
Thank you very much

Comment: I have also checked dundas Chart.

Comment: I can use chart1_PostPaint to get DataPoint's positionRel, How can I get DataPoint's Width and Height?